# Why can't I get my ruby require's to work properly?

Tags: ruby, require, ruby-1.9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove “.” from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)
>   [Require command not working within bash irb on Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228312/require-command-not-working-within-bash-irb-on-snow-leopard)
>   [Ruby `require` call fails on custom code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945114/ruby-require-call-fails-on-custom-code)

I'm running:

- OS X 10.6.8
- RVM 1.12.3 with Ruby 1.9.3

Let's say I have the following files in a directory:

#### a.rb

```
require 'b'
puts message_from_b
```

#### b.rb

```
def message_from_b
    "foo"
end
```

I get the following LoadError upon running **a.rb**:

> /Users/Alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- b (LoadError)

However, if I replace line 1 of **a.rb** with `require './b'`, it works fine.

When looking at other people's Ruby code, it seems that they don't need to specify the current directory for it to require a file in the same directory.

So, why do I have to do that? Is it something to do with my RVM install?

Comment: You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative for a discussion of why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

File `b.rb` is not in your load path. Either add `b.rb`'s directory to your load path

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__)) # assuming it's the current directory
```

or use

```
require_relative 'b'
```